# how to send verification email to users using Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to send verification email to users who just signed up. I have been looking for a solution for this and thought I found one, but it didn't work.
I checked out the Firebase Auth document and tried code on the page, but it also couldn't be the solution.

My code is below
The "try" actually runs when pressing the sign-up button and I can see it.
In the Firebase Auth console page, I can see the user just created but didn't get a verification email in the inbox.

```js
  const handleSignup = async (email, pswd) => {
    try {
      await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pswd);
      setSignupEmail("");
      setSignupPassword("");
      setSignupPasswordAgain("");
      signOut(auth);
      sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser);
      alert("Check your email for a verification link.");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: See if this helps.   In this article, we will see how to send the user verification email to the user, so that only verified users can be signed In to their account using Email Password Authentication.     https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-send-a-user-verification-mail-in-web-and-firebase/

Answer (score 0):

You call `sendEmailVerification()` after having called `signOut()` so `auth.currentUser` is `null` when you pass it to `sendEmailVerification()`. You should see an error logged in the catch block.

Moreover, both [`sendEmailVerification()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#sendemailverification) and [`signOut()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#signout) methods are asynchronous and return Promises.

The following should do the trick (untested):

```
  const handleSignup = async (email, pswd) => {
    try {
      await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pswd);
      setSignupEmail("");
      setSignupPassword("");
      setSignupPasswordAgain("");
      await sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser);
      await signOut(auth);
      alert("Check your email for a verification link.");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```